# jquery `.find()` use with `:not` selector is missing some elements (the selector is affected by the `.find()` invoking element, but it shouldnt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

#### problem

I have an element `$(elt_Main)` (`<span id="a">`)

I call `$(elt_Main).find(selector);` on it

With a selector `selector = ':not(span span)';`

But jquery is **not giving out all the child elements** I want.

#### ex [test1.html]

- say the content in html is::

  ```html
  <body>
  <span id="a">The first <span class="red">signature <span class="green">for the .find() <span class="blue">method accepts</span> a selector</span> <strong>expression</strong> of the <span class="green">same type that we can pass to the</span> $() function</span>. The <span class="red">elements</span> will be filtered by testing whether they match this selector; all parts of the selector <strong>must lie inside of an element</strong> on which .find() is called.</span>
  </body>
  ```
- the javascript is::

  ```js
    let elt_Main = document.getElementById('a');
    // ...
    html_ResultAppend += hr_3;
    selector = ':not(span span)';         // <<< watch
    jqElt = $(elt_Main).find(selector);   // <<< watch
  ```
- the js that provides output for debug is::

  ```js
    for (let o of jqElt) {
      html_ResultAppend += hr_4;
      html_ResultAppend += o.outerHTML;
    }
  ```
- the result of `jqElt` will be::

  ```
  <strong>expression</strong>
  <strong>must lie inside of an element</strong>
  ```
- but the **expecting result** should be::

  ```
  <span class="red">signature <span class="green">for the .find() <span class="blue">method accepts</span> a selector</span> <strong>expression</strong> of the <span class="green">same type that we can pass to the</span> $() function</span>
  <span class="red">elements</span>
  <strong>expression</strong>
  <strong>must lie inside of an element</strong>
  ```
- the pb & the cause is::

  **these 2 elements are missing**

  ```
  <span class="red">signature <span class="green">for the .find() <span class="blue">method accepts</span> a selector</span> <strong>expression</strong> of the <span class="green">same type that we can pass to the</span> $() function</span>
  <span class="red">elements</span>
  ```
- (I think) the logic of jquery is that (which is wrong)::

  `<span id="a"> <span class="red">signature ...`

  -> `<span class="red">signature ...` is inside a span `<span id="a">`

  -> we said `:not(span span)`

  -> so this should not be selected

  (^ same as above for `<span id="a"> <span class="red">elements</span>`)
- my **logic** is that::

  `<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`) is the element that invoke `.find()`

  **`<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`) itself should never *be taken into account / play any effect* when we use css selectors inside `.find()`**

  - otherwise, it wont make any sense in following examples::

    ex, say we do this: `$(elt_Main).find('span');`

    this should only find **child element** of `elt_Main` that is a `span` -- this is correct.

    if we take `<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`) into account when use use selector, this will select the `<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`) itself --  this is wrong.
  - in another words --

    when `.find()` is invoked by `<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`),

    the selector **should treat this (the element `<span id="a">` (`$(elt_Main)`) to search on) as if the tag `<span id="a">` doesnt exist** (-- it should not play any effect), and only search on the `innerHtml`.

#### to prove my logic -- example [test1.html test2.html]

- [plunker code ex: jquery `.find()` use with `:not` selector is missing some elements](https://plnkr.co/edit/2sIFPmJ5E1RP409g)

  the js selects the elements, and write to the html body.

  [image: plunker code image compare]
- **test1 uses `.find()` + `:not()`**

  **test2 uses only `:not()`**

  test2 removed the `<span id="a">` tag in `$(elt_Main)`

  - (-- just as I said above -- we should treat it as if the tag `<span id="a">` doesnt exist)
  - (if you think Im wrong on this, and you say: do not remove the `<span id="a">` makes test1 & test2 produce same result -> check out test1 vs test3 -- its even worse)
- we clearly see that

  `test1` output is missing elements

  `test2` output is correct

#### (back to the question)

"jquery `.find()` use with `:not` selector is missing some elements (the selector is affected by the `.find()` invoking element, but it shouldnt)"

So, Is jQuery wrong? or am I wrong? Why?

---

---

***Update***

#### discussions on "different semantic of `.find()` bt jQuery vs native Javascript"?

1. x

   as another answer points out,

   the native Javascript **`querySelectorAll`** does consider property **from the global html file scope**

   **not** from a **local sandbox scope** - starting from & limited to the inside of the invoking (parent) element `AA`, which was how I understood it.

   - [[ my understanding was due to

     1. my inexperience with (native) Javascript
     2. my personal preference on *how the rule should be applied when using selector from an element `AA`* is that:

        I prefer to select thing inside `AA`, ignoring all the effects from the outside scope -- so, treat those selections in `AA` as a `local sandbox scope`

        (again, this is just a subjective personal preference thing, but if rules are not designed in this way, of course then, I wont use it in this way)

     ]]

   -> so, I was wrong on the **understanding in native Javascript**
2. x

   though, another problem arise:

   so, the problem is **not** there is something wrong with `$(elt_Main).find(':not(span span)')`

   instead, **the problem is something is wrong with `$(elt_Main).find('span span')`** //doubt?

   -- `$(elt_Main).find('span span')` selects less than what normally expected

   -- according to the semantic in native Javascript

   -> so, jQuery is wrong on this //doubt?
3. x

   however, it seems the problem is actual that:

   **jQuery is intended to use a semantic of `find()` that is different than the semantic of `querySelectorAll()` in native Javascript** //doubt?

   (-- see the examples below for compare)

   -- which mean, yes, there is a `local sandbox scope`
4. x

   the problem remain is then:

   if "jQuery is intended to use a different semantic than its in native Javascript"

   then there is actually a **bug** in `$(elt_Main).find(':not(span span)')`

   --

   or if not

   then `$(elt_Main).find('span span')` is bugged

#### example

- [jsfiddle ex: different semantic of `.find()` bt jQuery vs native Javascript (updated with `:scope`)](https://jsfiddle.net/SelectNt/x7e2L3y0/)

  [image: different semantic of .find() bt jQuery vs native Javascript]

---

---

***Update***

- Added comparison with **"native Javascript with `:scope`"**
    <sub><sup>[[((forgot to mention))]]</sup></sub>

  Turns out, it seems the native Javascript with `:scope` has the same issue then?

  or **`:not()` was meant to view from a "global html file scope"**?

  -- which means, so, to let the effect of "local sandbox scope" play in, we need to specify `:scope :not(:scope span span)`, instead of simply `:scope :not(span span)`

  - [[this does output the desire output I intended to have (all the way up to) initially.

    if `:not()` behaves in this way, this does clarifies something.

    so, with such rule (such `:not()` behaves) native Javascript has no issue;

    as for jQuery... may still need to fix this //doubt?]]
- [jsfiddle ex: different semantic of `.find()` bt jQuery vs native Javascript (updated with `:scope`)](https://jsfiddle.net/SelectNt/x7e2L3y0/)

[image: different semantic of .find() bt jQuery vs native Javascript (updated with :scope)]

Comment: `So, Is jQuery wrong? or am I wrong? Why?` Not any kind of expert here but after reading your post I'd say the latter, because `.find()` really just returns you a set of descendants. It does not redefine any tree or scope or property of those descendants, like the fact that they are or are not "span inside a span". `$(elt_Main)` also just defines like the starting point, but not how to filter in `.find()`.

Comment: @TomYan (if I understand your comment correctly...)
1. 
> ".find() really just returns you a set of descendants." 
// yes, but the problem is its missing some elements. 
2.
> "It does not redefine any tree or scope or property of those descendants"
// it should, if you specify eg: `$(elt_Main).find('span');` / `$(elt_Main).find('span span');`, it should only search inside `$(elt_Main)`.
3.
> "$(elt_Main) also just defines like the starting point, but not how to filter in .find()"
// it is a starting point; but I specified the "selectors" in `find()` it should also select/filter those.

Comment: Let me put it this way: assuming A is a Martian and the parent of B, and B is inside a room and A is outside of the room. Now if you say, look for living things inside the room that has a non-Martian parent, then B must be ignored because it has a Martian parent. I know the model in this example isn't the same as the one in your question, but the key is (the same): neither do where you look at/from nor what's the filtering condition changes what kind of parent B has. `:not(span span)` does / should not magically redefine any elements property/parent. It's just an `if`-check.

Comment: And `$(elt_Main).find()` really just defines the set. It does / should NOT change any *fact* of each of the elements in this set.

Comment: Btw I can see why you see it your way: you thought that `$(elt_Main).find()` gives you a *tree* that the original root node (`elt_Main`) is "chopped off", so when the `:not(span span)` check is done, it works in a world / sandbox that the `span`s directly under `elt_Main` would seem "parentless", and hence they are not "span inside a span". But that line of code simply does not / is not expected to work like that at all. That's not the mechanism / rationale behind. It's really just like a two pass filter or so (`descendants of elt_Main`? -[true]-> `not "span inside a span"?`)

Comment: @TomYan 1.
> "neither do where you ... changes what kind of parent B has. :not(span span) does / should not magically redefine any elements property/parent"
// it deps on the scope you look at. if you look from the scope inside the `elt_Main`/`A` -> there is not such thing that "parent `elt_Main` takes an effect on the selector" -- the property (if this is what "property" you mean) does change. 
[^cts]

Comment: [^cts]
// I am not saying that now that `A` is not a parent element of `B`, `A` still is -- but you shouldnt view it as -- the "(parent) effect" `A` has on `B` should not play in when you are using selectors in `find()`.

Comment: [^cts]
// think about the **example** I talked above, (say `B` is a child element of `A`/`elt_Main` (thats not nest inside any other span,)) if the **`parent effect`** (if this is what "property not change" you mean) still plays in, **what should be  `$('#A').find('span span');`?**, base on your logic, should this select `B`?, (My logic dont think so, and the fact is it wont).
// another ex, say you have `<div><span id="A"><span id="B">`, you invoke `$('#A').find('div span)`, dym this should select `B`?, (My logic dont think so, and the fact is it wont).

Comment: [^cts]
2.
> "you thought that $(elt_Main).find() gives you a tree that the original root node (elt_Main) is "chopped off""
// yes, this is what i mean.
> "so when the :not(span span) check is done, it works in a world / **sandbox** that the spans directly under elt_Main would seem "parentless","
// yes, this is what i mean. (but I mean right "inside" the `.find()`, not "after")

Comment: [^cts]
> "It's really just like a two pass filter or so (descendants of elt_Main? -[true]-> not "span inside a span"?)"
// your 2nd step sound like a property viewed "**globally** -- from the scope of the whole html file"; then **not** really, 2 steps should be "inside" one step (-- or you first go inside the "sandbox scope", then you many view it as "2 inner steps")

Comment: Well, I can reproduce the `the fact is it wont` cases, and *that* does seem like a bug to me. Apparently neither `"parent child"` nor `":not(parent child)"` will match in `$("parent").find()`: https://bpa.st/FQ57O

Comment: This question would have been much clearer if it had included a stack snippet. It's such a simple case that it would have taken far less typing than all the explanation above.

Comment: Also the real question is, in a descendant DOM query by selector, do elements above the starting point affect the selector interpretation? And the answer is "yes".

Comment: ... except when the answer is "no" :)  jQuery is indeed in disagreement with the native querySelector, but not in the `:not` case

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. It turned out to be more interesting than I expected.

Comment: Haven't done any test to find out the results or feasibility but wouldn't the negation of a scoped query be like `:not(:scope ...)`?

Comment: @TomYan Nvm hold on

Comment: Nvm from me too. I was really thinking of something like `:scope :not(:scope ...)`, I guess, which is actually silly. (With current jQuery you need a similar approach with like two `.find()` to get the proper `:not`.)

Comment: @TomYan 
++ Nvm I messed myself up... I even did so many test cases... 
++ <strike> I was trying to say """The point is the preceding `:scope` in `:scope :not(XXX)` needs to play the effect of "scoping", its not really about the `:scope` inside of `:not(:scope ...)`. But regardless of that, I have put multiple tests in the output picture just to compare, (and added 1 more that includes the case your want)."""
++ <strike> And which correspond to the statement (deleted now) """or :not() was meant to ...XXXX -- so, ignore the preceding local :scope? But this feels so wrong."""

Comment: [^cts]
But my test cases shown that they are indeed inside the `:scope`. (I saw too many outputs and thought should be less output results...)
=> so, nothing wrong, and it seems that indeed ":not() was meant to view from a "global html file scope""
-----
for now, Im not sure whether jQuery is wrong on this or not. 
(cuz, another thing is: `.not()` method in jQuery is same as `:not()`, then the sematic should not be changed simply for the case when `:not()` is inside `.find()`)
maybe we do need to use `:scope` like `:not(:scope ...)` in both native Javascript & jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector asks for any element that is not a `<span>` descendant of any other `<span>`. The descendant test does not apply only to the subtree beneath the starting point in the DOM (the element where the `.find()` is rooted); it involves the entire DOM. It *has* to work that way in general. Your claim that "it shouldn't" is a misunderstanding of how selectors work.

Because your starting element is itself a `<span>`, *all* the `<span>` elements in the subtree are descendants of a `<span>`, so none of them match the selector.

You can try your test with the native `.querySelectorAll()`:

```
let elt_Main = document.getElementById("a");
let targets = eltMain.querySelectorAll(":not(span span)");
```

and see what you get.

Here is a clearer example, using a `:not()` selector that involves a parent element of the starting point:

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");
let found = start.querySelectorAll(":not(.foo span)");
console.log("Found " + found.length + " elements");
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <span id="start">
    <span>Hello world</span> <b>a bold tag</b> <span>goodbye world</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Starting from the outer span, that selector (`:not(.foo span)`) asks for any element that is not a `<span>` that descends from an element with class "foo".  All the `<span>` tags beneath the starting point *do* match that selector in the `:not` because they all descend from the parent `<div>`. Thus the query finds only one element, the `<b>`.

As a general rule, finding a profound bug in a platform that's been in use for almost 20 years is fairly unlikely. Not impossible, but unlikely.

*edit* — It's pointed out in a comment that the simpler case of the selector "span span", that is, a positive search for any `<span>` that is a descendant of a `<span>` results in different behavior between jQuery's selector engine and the browser's native `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("jQuery finds " + $("#start").find(".foo span").length + " spans that descend from .foo");
  console.log("browser finds " + document.getElementById("start").querySelectorAll(".foo span").length + " spans that descend from .foo");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=foo>
  <span id=start>
    <span>Hello world</span> <b>bold</b> <span>goodbye world</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I find this very surprising. It should be noted that jQuery predates the introduction of the native DOM search methods by many years, so while this could be considered wrong (I certainly do) it must be understood that there may be millions of applications that depend on the old behavior, so changing it is probably not an option for the jQuery maintainers.

Comment: While it may or may not be the (original) concern of the OP, this is (from my POV) the real issue here: https://bpa.st/QBQTE. Although it seems to be somewhat documented (if I'm not misinterpreting): [`...; all parts of the selector must lie inside of an element on which .find() is called`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), it still look like an excuse of a bad "optimization" to me.

Comment: @TomYan I think that documentation is incorrect. It's fine to think it should work that way, but it doesn't. Look at the snippet in my answer: it's clear that *the browser itself* natively thinks that the descendant test should go all the way up the DOM.

Comment: @TomYan I suspect what the author of that documentation meant is that only elements that are descendants of the starting point will be included in the resulting jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah maybe. I consider the behavior in jQuery the result of a bug / wrong implementation anyway. IMO `$("span").find("span span")` should work like this: https://bpa.st/G22OQ

Comment: @TomYan that example is not the same test, and note that you're `.parents()` call will indeed go all the way up to the top of the DOM.

Comment: Also modern jQuery will defer to `.querySelectorAll()` whenever it can.

Comment: You seem to think that equivalent jQuery `.find()` would work as your plain JS snippet above. But it really does not. I think you should write a jQuery snippet yourself (so that it won't be affected by anyone else's *potential* misunderstanding / wrong code) and see.

Comment: @TomYan yes, I agree with you: I think that (*very* surprisingly) jQuery is misbehaving. In the `:not` case, it is correct (it does what querySelectorAll does), but in the "plain" case it disagrees. Thus it also disagrees with itself! It may be that it's legacy behavior that the maintainers cannot change because they don't want to break the Internet.

Comment: @TomYan I commented on a related bug on the jQuery github issues list. I think it may have something to do with how jQuery decides to defer to the native browser methods; they have to "fix" what the browser does to remain backwards-compatible with the old Sizzle library code. Or maybe it's always been inconsistent, who knows.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/5191

Comment: From reading through a couple other bugs, it seems that the jQuery people really like the way their `.find()` search works, to the point that (if I read it correctly) they've actually petitioned W3C to change the spec! Personally I prefer the W3C way, but in my 15+ years of jQuery I've never noticed one way or the other. I think that's because of how I use `.find()` with my own code and coding style.

Comment: @Pointy @TomYan Its good to put an issue on the github. 
Check out my updated post above.
My current understanding is that *jQuery is intended to use a semantic of `find()` that is different than the semantic of `querySelectorAll()` in native Javascript*, but if so, bug remains.

Comment: @Nor.Z yes, you are correct. I've been using jQuery heavily for at least 15 years, and I've never noticed the `.find()` behavior, probably due to my coding preferences etc. It sure seems to me that the `:not` behavior is inconsistent, and that's why I logged the bug. The jQuery people seem very attached to their behavior so maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: @Pointy I forgot to bring up the case of `:scope`. (Was getting too much attention on those debates on jQuery `.find()` & `:not()` vs native Javascript.) It seems the native Javascript with `:scope` has the same issue then? (See my updated answer)

Comment: With `:scope`, I'm not sure I understand what your test is trying to show, but `:scope` and `:root` allow the meaning of a `:not` expression to be made explicit. I don't know whether jQuery currently understands those; it might.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have a speculation here so I'm just going to post it as an answer.

As I've written in my comments, essentially `$(selector).find(selector)` works like a two pass filter. It is not supposed to pose any sandbox-ish mechanism that blocks the the second pass of selection from "detecting" any fact / property of the candidates, including but not limited to their parent.

HOWEVER, what I suspect about `$(A).find(A B)` is this does NOT (but IMO should) work behind the scene like this:

1. select all A's descendants
2. select those from the selection returned by step 1 that are `B` and have an `A` ancestor (something like `foreach c in S: if c is B and c.hasAncestor(A): nS.add(c)`)

INSTEAD, it probably work behind the scene like this:

1. select all A's descendants
2. select those from the selection returned by step 1 that are A
3. select *the descendants* of the selection returned by step 2 that are B

which is probably equivalent to:

1. select the descendants of A (pass 1) that are themselves A (pass 2)
2. select the descendants of the selection returned by step 1 that are B (pass 3)

As you can see, the logic is twisted in the (speculated) approach behind the scene. What you get became a "three pass filter".

Here's an example which might give you a clearer idea on what I mean:

```js
const a = $("span").find("span span");
console.log(a.length);
console.log(a.get(0).textContent);

const b = $("span").find("span").find("span");
console.log(b.length);
console.log(b.get(0).textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<span>A<span>B<span>C</span></span></span>
```

In other words, what `$("span").find("span span")` should (IMO) do is:

> Among the descendants of "span" selection, select spans that are inside a span

But what it (seem to) really does:

> Among the descendants of "span" selection, select spans inside those that are spans

As noted in the other answer, when `:not()` is involved, such problem does not occur. I suspect (again) that it is because the negation makes it harder to *look* right when you twist the logic as I stated.

I don't consider the current way that the descendant selector is implemented correct. I do wonder how the jQuery devs would argue about it though. (But this is really just my speculation. I haven't check any source code or so to make sure it is 100% the case.)

Comment: Might need to look at the source code of jQuery... (which is hard.) (and need to clarify the concept & logic). 
Waiting for more people & comments. Appreciate your work and discussions. :)